# Why is there this block of white space above my button?

Tags: html, css, nativescript

In my NativeScript project with Angular, I'm making a page with a slide out side navigation bar. I was able to get the nav bar working but for some reason, I now have a white block of space above the content that I actually want there and can't find out how to get rid of it. [Here's a playground demo of what I'm doing](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=yRM2NL&v=9) and here's the code and html:

.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import { RadSideDrawer } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer";
import { RadSideDrawerComponent } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular";

@Component({
selector: "Home",
moduleId: module.id,
templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

    public isDrawerOpen: boolean;

    constructor(private _changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    @ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent) public drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;
    private drawer: RadSideDrawer;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.drawer = this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer;
        this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.isDrawerOpen = false;
    }

    public openDrawer() {
        if (!this.isDrawerOpen) {
            this.drawer.showDrawer();
            this.isDrawerOpen = true;
        }
        else {
            this.drawer.closeDrawer();
            this.isDrawerOpen = false;
        }
    }
}
```

.html file:

```html
<ActionBar title="Leagues" class="action-bar">
    <ActionItem>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button class="fa" text="&#xf0c9;" fontSize="20" (tap)="openDrawer()"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ActionItem>
</ActionBar>

<RadSideDrawer tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton drawerContentSize="200">
    <StackLayout tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout">
        <StackLayout class="sideTitleStackLayout">
            <Label text="Commissioner Tools"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <ScrollView>
            <GridLayout columns="45, 150" rows="25, 25, 25, 25, 25" class="sideStackLayout">
                <Label text="&#xf091;" class="sideLabel fa" row="0" col="0"></Label>
                <Label text="Create a League" row="0" col="1"></Label>
                <Label text="&#xf500;" class="sideLabel fa" row="1" col="0"></Label>
                <Label text="Create a Team" row="1" col="1"></Label>
                <Label text="&#xf133;" class="sideLabel fa" row="2" col="0"></Label>
                <Label text="Create Schedule" row="2" col="1"></Label>
                <Label text="&#xf303;" class="sideLabel fa" row="3" col="0"></Label>
                <Label text="Record Results" row="3" col="1"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout tkMainContent>
        <ScrollView orientation="vertical" class="pageBackground">
            <StackLayout class="pageBackground" height="100%" orientation="vertical">
                <StackLayout class="m-5"></StackLayout>
                <Button text="Basketball" class="basketballClass" style="width: 95%; height: 50; margin-top: 1%; border-width: 2px; border-color: black;"
                    (tap)=chooseLeague()></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

for reference, this is what it currently looks like:
[image]

and this is what I want it to look like:
[image]

Comment: Consider learning to debug/inspect your app. You can do it in both Safari and Chrome. A basic (if not decent) understanding of HTML markup and CSS is required to customize mobile apps. Ref your question, it's most likely a top margin on the button + a padding on the page container.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu how do I view it in chrome if it's on my phone?

Comment: It's called remote debugging. For iStuff debug using Safari, for Android use Chrome. You can inspect anything on any device using a computer.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu interesting, thanks! i didn't know that was possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disable the **iosOverflowSafeArea** when you are using the ScrollView.

Just the change you code to disbale it.

`<StackLayout tkMainContent iosOverflowSafeArea="false">`

I have updated the playground [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=yRM2NL&v=10).

P.S. With the release of the iPhone X and iOS 11 Apple has brought their users a new ultra-immersive user experience where the apps visibly stretch the entire surface of the phone. The iosOverflowSafeArea property defaults to true for all components that can have children. We can call them containers. These are the six layouts, ScrollView, ListView and Repeater. For more reading on this you can refer [here](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-5-ios-safe-area-support).

Comment: thank you so much! that worked perfectly, I didn't even know that was a think haha thanks!