# Side Drawer Scrollview Issue in IOS

Tags: scrollview, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I face the issue in `ScrollView` when implementing it inside of `Radsidedrawer`.

The following code snippet was Radsidedrawer Main Content Code

```
<StackLayout tkMainContent>
    <StackLayout [visibility]="isContentVisible ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

MyComponent file

```
<ActionBar title="Change Password">

</ActionBar>
<side-drawer>
    <GridLayout rows="auto,*" column="auto" class="page">
        <StackLayout  row="0" column="0" orientation="vertical" class="main-parent"> 
         .....
        </StackLayout>

        <Image height="10%" id="cpImage" row="1" column="0" class="ads" stretch="aspectFill" (tap)="NavigationToWeb()"></Image>
    </GridLayout>
</side-drawer>
```

Sample Images

[image]

I mentioned the empty space in red color it only occurs in `iOS`

Comment: Can you share a Playground where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: @Manoj okay I update playground

Comment: code you have shared doesn't contain ScrollView

Comment: @Manoj Playground It was worked perfectly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318354/why-is-there-this-block-of-white-space-above-my-button/54319433#54319433

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the iosOverflowSafeArea when you are using the ScrollView.

Just the change you code to disbale it.

```
 <GridLayout rows="auto,*" column="auto" class="page" iosOverflowSafeArea="false">
```